# How can I create irregularly apportioned vertices in regularly distributed vertices in a loop, without changing the loop?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, looping

As already mentioned above, I would like to distribute all vertices evenly in a loop. The loop or curve should not be changed; is there method that does this for me automatically.
[image]

as you can see, the vertices are distributed irregularly.
now I want to distribute the vertices evenly, without changing the curve or loop

Comment: The LoopTools add-on (included with Blender) has a space function which I think will do what you need.

Comment: Quick reaction Lewis, you're absolutely right, that's exactly what I needed. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The shipped Loop Tools add-on > *Space* option may do exactly what you want..

[image]

It can make a cubic interpolation from existing irregular points, resulting in a smooth curve fit. You can set it to 'Linear'..

[image]

.. which will be more faithful to the jumps in tangent directions created by gaps between vertices before the operation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the Loop Tool has brought me forward. Exactly the space function has brought me further. It was nice that you answered me so quickly, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you will get a 100% semi-circle but the result will be pretty good if you use the *LoopTools* addon. Activate it, then press <kbd>W</kbd> > *LoopTools* > Space to make the space between each vertex equivalent. Then again press <kbd>W</kbd> > *LoopTools* and *Relax*. Note that you can play with the parameters on the bottom of the *Tools* panel on the left of the 3D View (displayed with <kbd>T</kbd>)

Comment: Also to you, thank's a lot much for the detailed information. A little supplement, if the Loop Tool is activated on Blender 2.8 (2019-01-10) then you need only a right-click, to choose what you want.